# Responsive SVG, zoom in the center of x axis not resize

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to make an SVG responsive in the x-axis but I don't want it to scale with the window. In fact, I would like to make it keep the same aspect ratio, the same height, and also fill the same parent div, so it would be a zoom in the view box in the center of the width axis.

It would look like this :
[image]

I'm currently playing around with the view box and I have

> (for WinWidth < SvgWidth && WinWidth > SvgWidth/ 2)
> , deltaWidth = SvgWidth - WinWidth

```
viewbox = ((deltaWidth / 2)     0     (SvgWidth - deltaWidth)     SvgHeight)
```

But this is not working as there are still blank spaces on top and bottom of the parent div. Can you please explain to me what am I getting wrong?  I suppose it's because the ratio between width and height is no longer the same but i dont find how to arrange that. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use the `preserveAspectRatio"` attribute. For example you can have ` height="100vh" width="100vw" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"`

Comment: Nice, i never heard about the Slice option .. should have, that's cleaner than my way of doing ! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought, it was linked to the ratio of the svg not being the same as the ratio of the window. Here is what I simply made. As I didnt see anything on the internet about that, maybe it can help, enjoy :)

```
ratioWidth = SvgHeight * WinWidth / WinHeight
viewBox= ((SvgWdth - ratioWidth / 2) 0 ratioWidth SvgHeight)
```

But as enxaneta said, you can do it with `height="100vh" width="100vw" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice", in my point of view it's cleaner.